# Converting sql data before presenting it in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to modify an existing notepad example from the Android Developer site. I have a database with an existing column named `CREATED_DATE`(of the note) but the data for that column is presented as `System.currentTimeMillis()`. This is all good and probably in line with conventions since it's created by the developers.

But my problem is that I want to present the date in a `ListView` using the format `"30 sep"`. My problem, how do I convert the data to that format before presenting it in the `ListView`? Right now I'm using this kind of adapter:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.noteslist_item, cursor,
        new String[] { Notes.TITLE, Notes.CREATED_DATE }, new int[] { R.id.note_title, R.id.note_date });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, I've figured out how to convert `currentTimeMillis()` to today's date but how can I convert the data coming from the cursor before I toss it into the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, take a look at the [`Date`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) and [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) classes in order to convert your ms `long` into a `String` representation.

(There are lots of examples on stackoverflow on how to actually use those classes)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the ViewBinder. Have a look at this [Changing values from Cursor using SimpleCursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609126/changing-values-from-cursor-using-simplecursoradapter/4774370#4774370)
It helped me..