# Android - Can you update a Cursor for SQLite results?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

One of my methods returns a Cursor from some SQLite query results.

As I'm navigating through the cursor, there are some records I want to change/update. Can I update directly with the cursor? Or do I have to manually `UPDATE` using the record ID from the cursor?

Comment: i know it's late , but i need to understand what do you want exactly , you want to update some record in database and update their values in the cursor without making a re-query to db ?

Comment: Yes. However I misunderstood the way cursors work when I asked this question.

Comment: i made solution , where i have a 5k row in cursor that get displayed in a list view now if the user click on a button i have to make an update to database and modify the cursor value since a UI element depend on that , i made this and i avoided the requery issue by modify the cursor values and make the update to database . is that good ,or not ?

Comment: one can chnage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609126/changing-values-from-cursor-using-simplecursoradapter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not directly update records with the cursor. Read the [Android Cursor doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).

Comment: I think, one can chnage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609126/changing-values-from-cursor-using-simplecursoradapter

Comment: @ShirishHerwade To me it seems the linked discussion doesn't talk about writing anything to database. It just offers solution to filter/transform the data that is read.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a Content Provider that allows to update the record, in short you need to override the update function in your ContentProvider class.

```
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs)
```

In short you'll have to update them, this is not done directly from the data received in the Cursor.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and [this](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/) link should help.

Answer (score 0):

To do that the best way is to implement a content provider for your data http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

You can use framework like datadroid for that http://datadroid.foxykeep.com/