# Overriding SimpleCursorAdapter incorrect data and position returned

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm currently attempting to override a simplecursor adapter to allow me to use a imagbutton for each listitem.

Code so far:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    Cursor mCursor;
    final int tIndex;

    final class ViewHolder{
        public TextView textView;
        public ImageButton imageButton;

    }

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        mCursor = c;
        tIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.TASK);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)){
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            final int i = position;
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview,parent,false);
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskName);
            viewHolder.imageButton = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_task);
            viewHolder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "It Works: " + i);
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }

            String task = mCursor.getString(tIndex);
            viewHolder.textView.setText(task);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I use my parent activity to display the contents of the database, and use an alternate activity to add data to the database. I call finish() on the alternate activity to ensure the user is returned to the parent activity, in the parent activity in the onResume() method I use:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    myCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor = db.getAllRows());
    list.startLayoutAnimation();
    amountTasks();
}
```

When the user is returned to the parent activity, the data is incorrectly showed, the text of the listview will be a duplicate of the last entry, and the position will be 0.

I have found that if i change the return statement to:

```
return super.getView(position,convertView,parent)
```

The text is correctly shown, but the position still returns 0.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: in general dont extend SimpleCursorAdapter, use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html instead

Comment: @pskink Thank you for your suggestion, I will look into the implementation of the mentioned function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use bindview instead of getview, also much simpler to implement.

Credit to Stewart & pskink:

```
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        final int i = cursor.getPosition();
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.edit_task);
            viewHolder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG","Position: "+i);
                }
            });
    }
```

getview override wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used cursors in a while are you sure you have to `moveToPosition()` in the `getView()` method? AFAIK, all you need to handle is your ViewHolder and set values, you should not be changing the position in the cursor.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955532/listview-and-customadapter-extending-simplecursoradapter), it may help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however doing so caused the entire listview to be populated with the 1st entry of the database, therefore that is why I added the mention method.

Comment: Have you tried to use the bindView() and newView() methods instead of getView()?

Comment: I haven't tried oveririding those methods, @pskink also suggested to try using bindView instead, I will try to get it working using bindview :)